# JQuery function does not respect clicked component

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a product page where you can make customizations to the product such as adding or removing "ingredients" and for each customization that can be added or removed I create an input with a + and - button to increase or decrease my choice.

I inform via parameter to the javascript function the component (input) that will receive the increment or decrement, the maximum value that can be increased, the minimum value (decrement) and the increment interval.

However, for each possible customization in the product I must present a component like this:

```
<div class="qty mt-5">
    <span class="minus" name="diminuir[]" onclick="AumentaDiminui('qty_4', 0, 5, 1)">-</span>
    <input type="number" class="count" name="qty_4" value="0" step="1" max="5" min="0">
    <span class="plus" name="aumentar[]" onclick="AumentaDiminui('qty_4', 0, 5, 1)">+</span>
</div>
```

And this is my java script function that should add or subtract the value and present it in the correct input

```
<script>
    function AumentaDiminui(controle, valorMinimo, valorMaximo, valorIncremento) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[name="aumentar[]"]').click(function () {
                if ($("[name=" + controle + "]").val() == valorMaximo)
                    return;
                $("[name=" + controle + "]").val(parseInt($("[name=" + controle + "]").val()) + valorIncremento);
            });
            $('[name="diminuir[]"]').click(function () {
                if ($("[name=" + controle + "]").val() <= valorMinimo) {
                    $("[name=" + controle + "]").val(valorMinimo);
                    return;
                }
                $("[name=" + controle + "]").val(parseInt($("[name=" + controle + "]").val()) - valorIncremento);
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

It turns out that the value is not incremented by 1 in 1 as I inform via parameter and if I have more than one component on the screen, when clicking on + or - the value of all inputs are changed regardless of the button I click on

Comment: Why do you have a document.ready call inside of a function? Get rid of that. Also now I seee you are binding click events on click???

Comment: @epascarello I got rid of the code snippet mentioned but the problem continues. I am linking an event to the click of the span element (+ or -) to change the value of the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments about your code:

- If jquery will handle the click events on the `<span>`, one should not define a onclick event in the span tag.
- There is no need to define a function. You can just wait for the `ready` event and then monitor for clicks on both `<span>` (using the jquery `.click()` function).
- You can access the values of min and max value defined in the `<input>` using the jquery `.attr()` function.

This is a working code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.qty .minus, .qty .plus').click(function () {
  
    var input = $(this).parent().find('input[type=number]');
    var newVal = +input.val();
    
    var step = +input.attr('step');
    
    if ($(this).hasClass('plus')){
      newVal += step;
    } else {
      newVal -= step;
    }
    
    var min = input.attr('min');
    var max = input.attr('max');
    
    if (newVal > max) {
      newVal = max;
    } else if (newVal < min){
      newVal = min;
    }
    
    input.val(newVal);
    
  });       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Step: 1</p>
<div class="qty mt-5">
    <span class="minus">-</span>
    <input type="number" class="count" value="0" step="1" max="5" min="0">
    <span class="plus">+</span>
</div>

<p>Step: 2</p>
<div class="qty mt-5">
    <span class="minus">-</span>
    <input type="number" class="count" value="0" step="2" max="5" min="0">
    <span class="plus">+</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer, but you've missed one important point that the value does not always increment/decrement by 1. It's a parameter in the original code.

Comment: @francisco neto Your code works perfectly! But if I have several inputs and each with their respective + / - buttons? I need to identify the span that was clicked and the corresponding input that the value should be changed.

Comment: it works even with several inputs. I edited the code and now it has three inputs. And it works. take a look

Comment: you are right. The step can be also retrieved from the <input> using the `var step = +input.attr('step');`. Take a look at my edited code now to see steps working.

Answer (score 0):

There is a *much* easier way to do this, with just a few `data-*` attributes. This will work on any number of `div` elements with these attributes and a plus and minus button.

```js
$('.qty').on('click','.minus', function(){
   var $parent = $(this).parent();
   var min = $parent.data('min');
   var inc = $parent.data('inc');
   
   var $input = $(this).siblings('.count');
   var val = parseInt($input.val(),10);
   if(val > min)
    $input.val(val - inc);
})

$('.qty').on('click','.plus', function(){
   var $parent = $(this).parent();
   var max = $parent.data('max');
   var inc = $parent.data('inc');

   var $input = $(this).siblings('.count');
   var val = parseInt($input.val(),10);
   if(val < max)
    $input.val(val + inc);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="qty mt-5" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-inc="1">
    <span class="minus">-</span>
    <input type="number" class="count" name="qty_4" value="0" step="1" max="5" min="0">
    <span class="plus" name="aumentar[]">+</span>
</div>

<div class="qty mt-5" data-min="0" data-max="100" data-inc="5">
    <span class="minus">-</span>
    <input type="number" class="count" name="qty_4" value="0" step="1" max="5" min="0">
    <span class="plus" name="aumentar[]">+</span>
</div>
```

You could also choose to read `min`, `max` and `step` from the `input` if you prefered with much the same logic.

Answer (score -1):

create an jquery extension

```
(function($){
    $.fn.AumentaDiminui = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({ control: null,  minvalue:1, maxvalue: 5 , action:'+'   }, options );
        var curval =  $(settings .control).val (); 
        if ('+'==settings.action){
        if  (curval==settings.maxvalue) return;
        curval++;
        }
        else {
        if  (curval==settings.minvalue) return;
        curval++;
        }
        $(settings .control).val (curval);
      
    };
 }(jQuery));
```

call so as

```
$('div.qty.mt-5 span.minus').click(function (){ $.fn.AumentaDiminui({ action:'-', control:'div.qty.mt-5 input.count' }); });
$('div.qty.mt-5 span.plus').click(function (){ $.fn.AumentaDiminui({ action:'+', control:'div.qty.mt-5 input.count' }); });
```

Comment: Your solution works partially because as I have several inputs in my html code, they are all modified at the same time